# How to show div that is display:none if shopping cart is empty of items?

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, hidden

Following the logic of the code below:

```
<div id="add-to-cart-widget">
<div class="simpleCart_items"><div class="cartHeaders">
<div class="itemthumb">thumb</div><div  class="itemTotal">Total</div><div class="itemremove">remove</div>  </div>
</div>
<div id="if-cart-empty" style="display: none">Your cart is empty.</div>
```

Items only appear in cart if `.itemContainer` is present. For each item added to cart, a new container is created and put inside `#add-to-cart-widget`.

Using jQuery, how do I check if `#add-to-cart-widget` is showing `.itemContainer` and if none present then show div `#if-cart-empty`?

### ------- EDIT ------- (works in jsFiddle but not on site)

This is the exact code that I put into the post on my site. I added an extra `.click` event on `.itemremove` so you can click the "remove" container and test it out:

```
<div id="add-to-cart-widget">
<div class="simpleCart_items">
    <div class="cartHeaders">
            <div class="itemthumb">thumb</div>
            <div  class="itemTotal">Total</div>
            <div class="itemremove">remove</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="if-cart-empty" style="display:none;">Your cart is empty.</div>
    </div>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!$('.itemContainer').is(":visible")) {
    $('#if-cart-empty').show();
} else {
    $('#if-cart-empty').hide();
}

$('.itemremove').click(function(){
 $('.itemContainer').hide();
});
    });
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
  .itemContainer {background:red;}
</style>
```

### FORGOT to put a link to the test site:

http://sitetestexample.blogspot.com/p/cart-empty-test.html

This is what the `#add-to-cart-widget` looks like when an item is added to the shopping cart (the first code above is what it looks like without any items in the cart) :

```
<div id="add-to-cart-widget">
<div class="simpleCart_items">
<div class="cartHeaders">
<div class="itemthumb">thumb</div>
<div class="itemTotal">Total</div>
<div class="itemremove">remove</div></div>
    <div class="itemContainer"><div class="itemthumb">
       <img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CB2o1hPryRo/Ub54iT3ggVI/AAAAAAAAFJY/W6iBiOFaggo/s1600/picture+001.jpg">
</div>
<div class="itemTotal">$80,000.00</div>
<div class="itemremove"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.items['c3'].remove();">x</a> 
</div></div></div>
<div id="if-cart-empty" style="display:none;">Your cart is empty.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE ANSWER

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/BAs2m/8/

After you remove the item, you need to check again the itemContainer is still there or not.

Since you are deleting item, I suggest to use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

```
checkCart();

$('.itemremove').click(function(){    
    $('.itemContainer').remove();  
    checkCart();
});

function checkCart(){
    var item = $('.itemContainer');
    if (item.length > 0) {
        $('#if-cart-empty').hide();
    } else {
        $('#if-cart-empty').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The jsFiddle is perfect. However, for some odd reason, it doesn't work on my site. I spent a few hours yesterday and today trying to figure out why. I added an edit to the post, any ideas?

Comment: check my update answer and, move this script inside document ready.

Comment: I copy and pasted your updated answer directly into my post (with the document ready) and still nothing. I forgot to put the test link, it's now on there so you can see what I mean.

Comment: You have to delete the ...<div class="itemthumb">thumb</div>
            <div  class="itemTotal">Total</div>
            <div class="itemremove">remove</div>... inside itemContainer, so that the script will know there is no item, and will show 'no item in cart'

Comment: you also need to add .itemthumb in ... if (!$('.itemContainer .itemthumb').is(":visible")) {...});

Comment: Well that would explain it. Okay, in the original site (not the test site), there is a section called .cartHeaders in which .itemthumb, .itemTotal, and .itemremove remain within the #add-to-cart-widget and when an item is added to the cart, the actual variables for that item creates a new class called .itemContainer which also has that items .itemthumb, .itemTotal, and itemremove. This happens just under the .cartHeader section. Therefore, .itemContainer is the only DIV in which is either visible or not. All the others are always there under the cartHeaders within #add-to-cart-widget.

Comment: Does that new info above make any difference in the code? That's why I removed the    if (!$('.itemContainer .itemthumb').is(":visible")) { Do I still need that?

Comment: I updated my post explaining what I just wrote here with the actual code of what it looks like when an .itemContianer is added to the cart.

Comment: no need to add .itemthumb, you are correct, so can you post both blank cart html and after add item cart html, so that i can test again.

Comment: try this if ($('.itemContainer .itemthumb').html()== 'thumb') {
    $('#if-cart-empty').show();
} else {
    $('#if-cart-empty').hide();
}

Comment: bcoz your itemcontainer is aldy visible with itemheader, thats why.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this, you likely spent more time on this than you would have liked. I really appreciate you for it. And you probably don't want to hear about more problems lol but I'm using Blogger.com as a platform. Blogger gives errors with the code .html Can we use a something else for that code besides .html?

Comment: Oh and sorry, I likely wasn't clear. In the "Before add item" there is no ".itemContainer". The .itemContainer only appears when an item is added.

Comment: There is no ".itemContainer" in the ".cartHeader" but yes the ".cartHeader" does have the other div's

Comment: So the div section of the jsfiddle should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BAs2m/3/ That likely changes the jQuery too, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We're so close, I can taste it. I hope you didn't give up on me. All the div's are correct now. I have the exact HTML codes for an empty cart and when an item is present in cart. Just need the corresponding jQuery code to check if .itemContainer is present in #add-to-cart-widget and if not then show #if-cart-empty and visa versa.

Comment: check my update answer and demo again, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/BAs2m/5/, hope this works with your Blogger :)

Comment: Thank you so much for sticking with me. No error on Blogger this time but I can't seem to get the updated jsFiddle to work. I added a click function to the .itemremove, since this is exactly how the live Blogger site works. And I'm not seeing the #if-cart-empty appear when the .itemremove div is clicked on to remove the .itemContiner http://jsfiddle.net/BAs2m/6/ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check update answer and demo again, I wrote a function to check itemContainer, and on itemremove, I call it again. ** I also change hide() to remove() for itemremove. Hope this time works.

Comment: Thank you @yeyene It works in jsfiddle, on test blogger site, and sorta on live blogger site. Onload if the cart is empty, then it shows correctly. On load if the cart has items(s) then it also shows correctly (with hidden div). However, if I continue from that point and remove the last item from the cart, the div#if-cart-empty doesn't show again; only on reload. So it's close enough. If you know why it does this, great; if not, no problem. If you're still interested, I could give you the live url in private chat so you can look it over. There is obviously more info needed that I'm unaware of.

Comment: I got it working perfectly using .live, like this: $('.itemremove, .item_add').live('click', function(){  The only problem is that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer :( what a shame. I hate I.E.

Answer (score 3):

something like this would work :

```
function check_cart(){
   n = $('.itemContainer .itemthumb').length;
   if(n>0){ 
       $('.itemContainer').css('display','block');
       $('#if-cart-empty').css('display','none');
   }else{
       $('.itemContainer').css('display','none');
       $('#if-cart-empty').css('display','block');
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.itemremove, .itemadd').click(function(){
       check_cart();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer in a jsfiddle with no luck, likely I am doing something wrong. I couldn't get it to work on the site either, but I couldn't get the other answer to work either, so I don't feel it's your code that is wrong. Your code is very well thoughtout and I like it a lot. I gave it an upvote. Any ideas as to way it might not be working in the jsfiddle?